# What Method is used to identify when the user switches views in a tabview controller

Tags: uiviewcontroller, methods, uitabview

I am working on my first simple tabview controller app.  The first tab is a setup tab, and I just had a tester provide an unexpected use case. In order to address this use case, I need to execute when the user is leaving the view and before I load the next one.  Running code in the next view is too late.

What method is called from the current viewController at the point the user selects the TabView Controller to switch views?

I've tried using viewWillDisappear as the point to execute my code, but this does not appear to be called when switching views.

Comment: I am sure that the problem is that the Tabs have a higher priority, but I was positive that viewWillDisappear should have executed before the next view was brought in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, had to restructure the code to remove the dependency.  Have decided to store the state of each screen element and then access it when needed on the secondary view.